# How can I set the value of some columns to 0 (zero) while making a SELECT in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I’d like to set the value of some columns to 0 (zero) inside an SQL SELECT. That is, I want to override the values of the columns I get from the database, giving them values I decide (0, in this case), something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Age AS 0, CV7 AS 0, ...
FROM ...
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean `, 0 as Age, ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select a literal value and give it an alias in the query:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, 0 AS Age, 0 AS CV7
FROM   mytable
```